# UTM Link Generator Module For EE2

Tags: ee2, module

I need to implement UTM tags to all of the links I have in my site to track their progress, campaigns, sources etc. The following tags are being used to build a UTM tagged link:

- utm_campaign
- utm_source
- utm_medium
- utm_content
- utm_term

How would I be able to go about creating a module for EE to build these tags and append it to a landing page url to track? I would like it to be as dynamic as possible. Any guidelines would be very helpful!

[Here](http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/what-are-utm-tracking-codes-ht) is an awesome blog post about UTM tagging.

Comment: Why not just use an existing tool like this? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the link! I saw this and thought about using it, but my plan is to make a dynamic module for if i need those tag values from the database, this is why I want to do it via a module.

Comment: Ah - you may need to go into more detail about how you would want it to work, and which specific steps you need help with. As written, this is way too broad I think.